# O que significa esses dois "<<" dessa expressão?

Tags: javascript

Tenho esse código:

```
Math.floor((this.currentTime/1000/60)<<0);
```

Não entendi pra que serve esses dois `<<`.

Comment: Sei que sua pergunta é de JavaScript e que a indiquei como duplicata é de C e C++. Ocorre que os operadores `<<` e `>>` do JavaScript são os mesmos que os do C, C++, C# e Java. Então o que vale naquela outra pergunta, também vale na sua.